# Pandas analogue of JOIN with WHERE clause

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm doing joining of two dataframe (A and B) in python's pandas.

The goal is to receive all the pure rows from B (sql analogue- right join B on A.client_id=B.client_id where A.client_id is null)

In pandas all I know for this operation is to do merging but I don't know how to set up the conditions (where clause):

```
x=pd.merge(A,B,how='right',on=['client_id','client_id']
```

Comment: I guess you need only one 'client_id' in the `on` argument. Use a list if you want to join on more than one columns. Use `left_on` and `right_on` to specify the column for the two dataframes separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***option 1***
`indicator=True`

```
A.merge(B, on='client_id', how='right', indicator=True) \
    .query('_merge == "right_only"').drop('_merge', 1)
```

***setup***

```
A = pd.DataFrame(dict(client_id=[1, 2, 3], valueA=[4, 5, 6]))
B = pd.DataFrame(dict(client_id=[3, 4, 5], valueB=[7, 8, 9]))
```

***results***

[image]

***more explanation***
`indicator=True` puts another column in the results of the merge that indicates whether that rows results are from the left, right, or both.

```
A.merge(B, on='client_id', how='outer', indicator=True)
```

[image]

So, I just use `query` to filter out the `right_only` indicator then drop that column.

---

***option 2***
not really a merge.  You can use `query` again to only pull rows of `B` where its `'client_id'`s are not in `A`

```
B.query('client_id not in @A.client_id')
```

or an equivalent way of saying the same thing (but faster)

```
B[~B.client_id.isin(A.client_id)]
```

[image]

Comment: Really like the query() option here.

Answer (score 7):

For me, this is also a bit unsatisfying, but I think the recommended way is something like:

```
x = pd.merge(A[A["client_ID"].isnull()], B, 
             how='right', on=['client_id', 'client_id'])
```

More information can be found in the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html)

Additionally, you might use something like `A.where(A["client_ID"].isnull())` for filtering. Also, note my mistake in the previous version. I was comparing to `None`but you should use the `isnull()` function