# Pandas merging with condition on columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Greeting all,

Does anybody know how to join two dataframes according specific behavior using **pandas** please using pandas no other libraries.

like  `df1 inner join df2 where df1.t < df2.t ..`

Comment: what do you mean by `specific behavior` ?

Comment: for example :
`select * from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
where t1.ts < ts` 
ts is just normal timestamp how to do this kind of query in pandas

Comment: see if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867877/pandas-analogue-of-join-with-where-clause) answers your question

Comment: @LuizFernandoLobo unfortunately Nope even after reading [sql pandas comparaison](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_sql.html)

Answer (score 1):

Do it in sql, it comes with Python's standard library.

```
from sqlite3 import sqlite3
import pandas

# define your dataframes here 
df1 = ...
df2 = ...

# load the dataframes to memory
sql_ptr = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
df1.to_sql('df1', sql_ptr)
df2.to_sql('df2', sql_ptr)

# execute the query
df3 = pd.read_sql_query("select * from df1 inner join df2 on <insert columns to join on> where df1.ts < df2.ts", sql_ptr)
```

**And please keep in mind** that this query will do two different steps:

1. An inner join ==> an intersection on the specified columns
2. filter the result table on the given condition (! given on other columns !)

An inner join in relational algebra is an intersection between two sets ==> There is no such thing as inner join on condition between columns (other than the implied equality condition)

e.g. this query `"select * from df1 inner join df2 on df1.ts = df2.ts where df1.ts < df2.ts"` will yield an empty view cause inner join will find an empty intersection between the tables df1 and df2.

Comment: please read well my question dude I said only in pandas and i bold it I can do by using other libraries and the best one is `pandasql` but am checking if it exists in pandas in order to reduce libraries import ;)

Comment: libraries import (especially done with from .. import ...) doen't affect performance because all import does is loads a namespace, which is a list of available objects (in this case just the on imported), and a dictionary of methods to each of those objects.

Comment: when you are using some kind architecture for the deployment you have limited disk space you can use :-). This issue reported not about code performance vs library importing it is about pandas and merging.  ;-)

Comment: whenever you load the Python interpreter in memory all of its shared libraries(and hence all the standard library is loaded into memory). It's true that you will this way load the dataframes into memory again, but you will get rid of them as soon as sql_ptr is out of scope.